# Show E-Mail size in Office 365 or Exchange OWA (not Outlook)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, outlook-web-access

How can I check the size of emails via the Office 365 and Exchange OWA (Webapp / OWA) and is it even possible?

I've been looking through the settings for quite some time and I tried to think a little bit out of the box. I know for example that under macOS you have to hide the reading panel to be able to show add the size of mails via the top bar. However via the Browser Version of Outlook I cannot show it. The closest I get is to Sort by Size and then it only groups the mails like:

- Medium (25KB - 100KB)
- Big (100KB - 500KB)
- Very Big (500KB - 1MB)
- Hug (1MB - 5MB)
- Enormous ( > 5MB)

I ask because in our company we have some people with massive amounts of files (Mailbox Size of 49GB and growing), yet they use an iMac where there is no proper way to create a PST file that can be moved to a USB Stick or Network Drive and they want to be able to do it via the browser.

So if there are people who know of a way, I would highly appreciate their help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some research, you can see mail sizes via OWA light version:
[image]

Follow the below url to access owa light version: https://outlook.office.com/owa/?layout=light

For more details: [How to view Office 365 webmail in OWA light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wl_UI7DHFW4)

Comment: Yup this works. Just added "?layout=light" at the end of our Exchange OWA link and now I can see the Mail Size. Thanks a lot.
I would definetly not have found out about this without knowing that it exists. Just like secret menu items in some restaurant. ;)

Comment: As a bonus I managed to figure out that for the O365 version you need to use https://outlook.office.com/owa/?layout=light

Comment: Thanks. It's nuts that we have to resort to this kind of hackery to get simple but important info on corporate inboxes... :/